# How to prove $(A \cup (B - C)) \cap B^c \subseteq A - B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

## My try:

Suppose $(A \cup (B - C)) \cap B ^c$. We know $x \in A \cup (B - C)$ and $x \in B^c$. So, $x \in A$ or $x \in B - C$ and $x \in B^c$.

From there, I see two possible cases:
1 - $x \in A$ and $x \in B^c$. This leads to $x \in A - B$
2 - $x \in B - C$ and $x \in B^c$. Don't see how it's even possible to get into $x \in A - B$.

Maybe I don't need to divide into two steps.

Comment: Case 2 is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From there, I see two possible cases:
>
> 1. $x \in A$ and $x \in B^c$. This leads to $x \in A - B$
> 2. $x \in B - C$ and $x \in B^c$. Don't see how it's even possible to get into $x \in A - B$.
>
> Maybe I don't need to divide into two steps.

In the second case: ... $(B\smallsetminus C)\cap B^\complement$ is the empty set, which is a subset of any set, including $(A\smallsetminus B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider left-hand side of the formula.

\begin{align}
& (A\cup(B-C))\cap B^c &\\
& (A\cap B^c)\cup((B-C)\cap B^c) &&  \text{De Morgan's law}\\
& (A-B)\cup((B-C)-B) && \text{show that the second arg. to union is the empty set}\\
& (A-B)\cup\emptyset \\
& (A-B)
\end{align}
In fact you can put an equality relation sign between them.